# How to Prove Reflexivity, Antisymmetry, and Transitivity for $\mathcal{R}$ in a Partial Ordering?

Tags: number-theory, logic, relations

I have a question regarding the concept of a partial ordering, specifically with respect to a relation $\mathcal{R}$ defined on a set $A$. Here's the background:

Let $X=\{0,1\}$, and define the relation $\mathcal{R}$ on $A=X \times X$ as follows:

$(a, b) \mathcal{R} (c, d)$ if either of the following conditions holds:
i) $a < c$, or
ii) $a = c$ and $b \leq d$.

I am asked to demonstrate that $\mathcal{R}$ is a partial ordering. To do so, it must satisfy the properties of reflexivity, antisymmetry, and transitivity.

i) To prove reflexivity, I assume that $(a, b) \in A$ and show that $(a, b) \mathcal{R} (a, b)$.

ii) For antisymmetry, I assume that $(a, b), (c, d) \in A$ such that $(a, b) \mathcal{R} (c, d)$ and $(c, d) \mathcal{R} (a, b)$ are both true. Then, I argue that this implies $a = c$ and $b = d$.

iii) To prove transitivity, I assume that $(a, b), (c, d), (e, f) \in A$ and demonstrate that if $(a, b) \mathcal{R} (c, d)$ and $(c, d) \mathcal{R} (e, f)$, then this implies $(a, b) \mathcal{R} (e, f)$.

While I can follow the logical steps in the proof, I'm having difficulty fully understanding how the values of $a, b, c, d, e,$ and $f$ are related in each case and why certain conclusions are drawn. For instance, when proving antisymmetry, I'm uncertain why the conditions $a = c$ and $b = d$ are necessary and how these are derived from the given conditions.

If someone could provide a more intuitive explanation or a step-by-step breakdown of this proof, I would greatly appreciate it. I want to understand the reasoning behind each step.

Comment: In general, anti-symmetry says that for $x$ and $y$:  if $xRy$ and $yRx$, then $x = y$. So in this case, you need to show that if $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(a,b)$, then $(a,b) = (c,d)$. But $(a,b) = (c,d)$ holds if and only if $a = c$ and $b=d$. So that's where that comes from. Are you struggling with reflexivity and transitivity?